# jQuery: trying to validate an input text before submitting or placing the cursor in another field

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

how to validate an input text before submitting or placing the cursor in another field?

I've tried this below but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("input").keyup(function() {

        $("#jander").validate({

                rules: {
                    'coche4[marca]': "required"
                },

                messages: {  
                    'coche4[marca]': 'This field is required'
                }
        });

    });

});
```

Regards

Javier

Comment: Yes, it's true at beginning i didn accepts answers, because i didn't understand the mecanism.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form").validate({
    rules: {
      name: "coche4[marca]",
      required: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      comment: "Please enter a comment."
    }
  });
});
```

And remember the `return false;` statement.

Comment: Thanks, but where should i add "return false" exactly ?

Answer (score -1):

Example where to put return false:

```
$('#btnSend').click(function() {
   validation();
   return false;
}
```